# Rapid Resizing/Wiggling of VisualForce view

Tags: apex, visualforce, html

So I'm not a dev, I'm a lowly SysAdmin trying to come up with a fix for an issue that's causing serious issues with productivity with our staff. As such, I'm going to be as descriptive as possible, but I've never used Apex and all of this is way over my head. I'm pretty much all we have for IT, so here we are.

We have a call center setup when incoming calls will route to agents at their desks though Softphone and Incontact, pulling related cases with them on VisualForce. This also works with incoming Email.

In some cases, usually Email, there will be an issue with the page layout itself. Everything seems correct, but mousing over or clicking into text fields will cause them to slightly resize, jerking the layout around on the page. You'll go to click something, and it's not where you left it, so to speak. In some cases it's so bad that hovering over a button to select it will cause it to stutter so badly as that it isn't selectable. It's usually kind of a wiggle, back and forth very quickly, and sometimes objects on the screen will shuffle around until it settles.

Some of the more tech savy have figured out that swapping to windowed mode helps for a bit, but invariably it starts up again. It can be fixed short term by maximizing again, and so on.

The sales team are on low spec Intel i3 Windows 10 machines, native GPU, and in most cases dual vertical monitors, all running Chrome. It doesn't seem to be any better for those who have oriented horizontal.

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: What OS and browser are you observing this behavior on? Are you able to link to a screencast of some sort?

Comment: Machine specs are at the bottom of the post. I'm pulling a quick video together now.

Comment: You don't specify versions.